# Add query string to laravel 5 route which has optional parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('shop/browse/{category?}', 'ShopController@browse');
```

I would like to append some query parameters whether `category` param is present or not. Is there a better way to do it instead of passing optional params as null? e.g.

```
<a href="{{ route('shop.browse', ['category' => null, 'query_params' => $query_params]) }}">Browse</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('shop.browse', ['category' => null]) }}">
```

Then, any query parameters would simply be `<input>`s. On submit, each would be translated to a proper query string:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test"/>
// http://mysite/shop/browse?test=test, etc.
```

Then, instead of using a `<a href="..."`, use a `<button type="submit">` to handle.

Altogether:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('shop.browse', ['category' => null]) }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test"/>
  <button type="submit">Browse</button>
</form>
```